# How to search in MySQL exploded array data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table  structure as fallows

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | heading |  catid  |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | ajay |   xyz   | 1:25:22 |
| 2  |sanjay|   abc   |15:25:45 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

**If i get condition catid=22 then get result**

```
+---+-----+----+---------+
| 1 | ajay| xyz| 1:25:22 |
+---+-----+----+---------+
```

**If i get condition catid=15 then get result**

```
+---+-----+----+----------+
| 2 | sanjay| abc|15:25:45|
+---+-----+----+----------+
```

**If i get condition catid=25 then get result**

```
+---+-----+----+----------+
| 1 | ajay| xyz| 1:25:22  |
+---+-----+----+----------+
| 2 | sanjay| abc|15:25:45|
+---+-----+----+----------+
```

Comment: See normalisation.

Comment: whats the type of catid? varchar . Not sure if I understand it correctly but this should be possible with a simple 'like' operator.

Comment: Can you write fetch query here for above condition

Comment: you should normalize the table .

Answer (score 3):

You could use `FIND_IN_SET`, after replacing the colons in `catid` with commas:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('25', REPLACE(catid, ':', ',')) > 0;
```

But a good long term investment would be to normalize the `catid` data and get those IDs in separate records.

There is also a way to do this using the `LIKE` operator, but it is ugly:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONCAT(':', catid, ':') LIKE '%:25:%';
```

Comment: you are right. I deleted my answer :) +1

Comment: @godot There is a way to do this using `LIKE`, but it's ugly, which is why I used `FIND_IN_SET`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Absolutely agree with you